# Javascript: getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, static-libraries

I have a Javascript Library which looks like below

```
(function ($) {
    var gd_navbar = '#gd-navbar';
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            // set defaults
            var defaults = {
                applicationPath: null,
                //More Data
                enableRightClick: true
            };
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            // set global option params
            applicationPath = options.applicationPath;
            preloadPageCount = options.preloadPageCount;
            rewrite = options.rewrite;
            htmlMode = options.htmlMode;
            thumbnails = options.thumbnails;
            saveRotateState = options.saveRotateState;
            enableRightClick = options.enableRightClick;
            // assembly html base
            this.append(getHtmlBase);
            this.append(getHtmlModalDialog);
        }
    };
    function getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel() {
        return '<li id="gd-nav-right"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="gd-tooltip">Thumbnails</span></li>';
    }
})(jQuery);
```

now I am trying to execute the funciton called `getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel()`

so I simply write the below code

```
$.getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel()
```

but I got the below error

> $.getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel is not a function

I also tried with the below

jQuery.getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel()

but still I am getting same error,

what Do I need to do to work with these funciton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel` is currently just a plain variable name inside the IIFE - it won't be accessible anywhere else.

If you want it to be available from jQuery, assign it to `$`:

```
$.getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel = function getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel() {
  return '<li id="gd-nav-right"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="gd-tooltip">Thumbnails</span></li>';
}
```

Though, it currently just returns a *string*, which is a bit odd - did you mean to return a new element wrapped in a jQuery object?

```
$.getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel = function getHtmlNavThumbTogglePanel() {
  return $('<li id="gd-nav-right"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i><span class="gd-tooltip">Thumbnails</span></li>');
}
```